# What determines my horse's sprint duration and speed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My horse will gallop fine, but she becomes exhausted after a while and slows back to normal speed.

What determines the speed of this sprint, and more importantly, the duration?

Does it in any way depend on my stats and condition, or is it her personal trait?
Do horses differ in speed and sprint duration?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The duration of the gallop is governed by a horse's stamina. Regular horses have 106 points of stamina, Frost has 148 and Shadowmere has 198, allowing her to gallop for nearly twice as long as a regular horse, about 20 seconds.

The speed is governed by SpeedMult, which is 100 for all horses.

The rate of their recovery from exhaustion is governed by StaminaRate and StaminaRateMult, which are 10 and 100, respectively, for all horses, meaning that over lond distances Shadowmere will have galloped about as much as a regular horse.

Comment: Interesting information, especially concerning recovery from exhaustion. Does that mean that, the longer the sprint (as in time), the more time she needs to recover?

Comment: Yes, horse gallop functions very much like an NPC sprint. If you have access to the developer console, you can see how a horse's stamina will drop as it sprints and how it will replenish when not sprinting.

Comment: Thanks, @desaivv! You can use `modav` to apply a bonus or a penalty to any of the [actor values](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Actor_Value_Indices). You can use `getavinfo` to get detailed information about an actor's value, including the auto-calculated value, current modifier applied to it and whether they are permanent or not.