# My Skyrim horse can only gallop (sprint) for a few seconds, same as me. Why is this?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Being a horse, one would expect they could "sprint", ie. gallop, for a decent period of time. Mine (the first one I bought, at Whiterun stables), can only sprint for about as long as I can. That is, just several seconds. Then he goes back to cantering.

Is this normal? If so, what's the purpose of giving a horse (and apparently the hardiest of horses in Tamriel, or so I hear) so little fatigue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a horse actually faster than running?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/is-a-horse-actually-faster-than-running)

Comment: Not a duplicate - that question is about overall efficiency of riding vs running. This is specifically about a horse's gallop time vs cantering.

Comment: The answer here:  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/51210/174247  points out that Shadomere has the longest sprint time.... unfortunately, on a very long journey, he's no better than any of the other horses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal it's just how Bethesda wanted it....too bad because galloping for a longer period of time would have been fun :P

Comment: true that :P hehe forgot about him

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Bethesda wanted not to make horse travel to fast in order to increase the perceived size of the world.

Sprinting is there so you can put a little distance between enemies and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=7558) that allows horses to run longer and faster.

I greatly prefer it to the vanilla horses - it makes the horses feel much more useful.